# Limited Memory Usage by C# app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# application which I have compiled as 64bit and it is being run on a 64bit machine which has 32GB of RAM and is running windows server 2008. When it runs, the box is peaking at 9GB RAM used (5GB when the app isn't running).

I have a requirement to get this app to use more RAM. I have been looking around online and can't pinpoint exactly how this limitation is being caused. I looked into the use of the page file (although from what I read, the virtual memory should not be an issue in this case) and the page file size is by default currently set to around 32Gb

Can anyone else point me in the right direction. I'm very new to C# and visual studio so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: ASP.NET? Try looking at the config file. Anything in there that may be defining a limitation?

Comment: I'm not sure that the limitation you are describing comes from .Net/CLR.

.Net will quite happily continue to try and allocate memory, eventually throwing OutOfMemoryExceptions once it can't allocate any more memory.

The fact you say your program just reaches a limit makes me wonder if something else is causing the limitation.

Comment: maybe you should give more details about what the app does. if it has database connectivity (and if the sql server runs on the same machine) or if it loads big files into memory, etc.

Comment: I found this line in the config "<add key="MainDSN" value="data source=(local);packet size=4096;initial catalog=DotActivImportService;integrated security=SSPI" />". Could that 4096 be the limit?

Comment: How have you verified that your deployed process is being executed in 64-bit context? How have you verified that your app just does not actually use all the RAM that you are expecting? e.g. why do you want it to use more ram (asking because normally you just use what you need)?

Comment: The application I am working with is used to import large amounts of data from CSV or SQL flat files into databases. My bosses just want to app to run faster if possible

Comment: @Chris - I don't know much about your application, but at these huge memory usages it is far more likely that the high memory consumption is *slowing down* your application considerably as the garbage collector works overtime to collect and compact memory. Generally speaking an optimal approach would be to read the data in in small chunks or line-by-line and process them serially, keeping the memory usage to an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is probably just not allocating and holding "enough" memory. Try allocating 10 byte[] of 1GB each. This will succeed. And it is proof that the CLR is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong question. Your app using more RAM doesn't make it faster. You need to perhaps split your CSV loading tasks using multi-threading or better use bcp utility.